# Order JSON file from GET function in Angular?

Tags: angular, api

I am creating an Angular 2+ app that takes in an API url and organizes the content alphabetically from the GET call by a field in the data. I understand how to call the GET function, but I am confused on the best way to split up the data and reorganize it. For example, if the data queried from the GET call results in:

[{"id":1,"name":"Banana"},{"id":2,"name":"Apple"}]

as a string (using JSON.stringify) and want to sort each entry by name, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sort()

```
var dt=[{"id":1,"name":"Banana"},{"id":2,"name":"Apple"}]

dt.sort((a,b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0)); 
console.log(dt)
```